# Jasmine fails when same test is run twice

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have this situation where the code is working, but when I run the same test twice, it fails and I don't know why. Looks like there is a gotcha I am not aware of in the beforeEach();

Two beforeEach are run. One in the first one in the top "describe" and the following one that inside the previous "describe".

Anyone knows what is the problem here?

```
describe("[data-add-selected].click()", function () {
  var option;

  beforeEach(function () {
    initialize();
    option = container.find('.source .option:last');
    option.addClass('selected');
    container.find('[data-add-selected]').click();
  });

  it("this succeeds", function () {
    expect(source.getOptions().length).toEqual(1);
    expect(destination.getOptions().length).toEqual(2);
  });

  it("this FAILS", function () {
    expect(container.find('.source .option').length).toEqual(1);
    expect(container.find('.destination .option').length).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

[Here](https://github.com/koinejs/WebComponents/blob/d8708a7e4354c2ea69eb5b2ddb4e21c9ef486d76/specs/Koine.WebComponents.FancySelect_spec.js#L120) is the work in progress (that works on the browser but fails on the test).

TIA.

Comment: are you resetting your dom for every test?

Comment: It looks like it's interacting with the DOM, and `option.addClass('selected');` actually changes DOM state. Are you resetting that DOM state between tests? Is that what `initialize()` does?

Comment: How do I reset the DOM @DanielA.White?

Comment: @AlexWayne I updated the question and pasted the github link to my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/mjacobus/9f03b814f1b665dbe54f) you have provided and your comments about the behavior of the tests as you manipulate them in various ways, the most probable cause of the issue is the fact that you are using the same `id` twice.

Here is a line from `beforeEach` block:

```
container = $('<div id="container" />');
```

You create a `div` with `id` equal to "container". Now the problem lies here:

```
$('body').append(container).append(sourceElement).append(destinationElement);
container = $('#container');
```

After the first test everything is fine, because there is only a single "container" in the body. But as you run the second test, and consequently the `beforeEach` block again, another "container" is appended to the body. Now there are 2 `div` elements with the `id` "container", and the behavior of the query selector is undefined.

A good solution would be to add an `afterEach` block in which you do cleanup after testing -- in this case removing the container.

```
afterEach(function () {
    $('#container').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @STT. Yeah, I thought it could be that. But actually it fails because that instead of 4 there's only one. Here's the simplified gist [a gist](https://gist.github.com/mjacobus/9f03b814f1b665dbe54f):

Comment: I see, I did not see the second `beforeEach` in the `describe` block. I am thinking now that perhaps this has to do with the `onclick` listener. Perhaps in your decorator the options are logically moved, but in the DOM they stay in the same place?

Comment: it does not seem to be the case @STT. If I comment out the lines 90 and 92 (hence grouping all the assertions in one "it") it works. So it the listener is working. Besides, it works on a manually browser test. =/

Comment: I have another idea -- in line 63 you append a `div` with and `id` "container". Notice that you are doing this twice (before each test) -- maybe it confuses the query selector then (two elements with the same ID). Try to add an `afterEach` block in which you remove the container from `body`.

Comment: you nailed it! The tests in the gist pass after I ```$('#container').remove()```! Thank you! Would you create an answer so I can pick it as the correct one? Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll just edit this one, you're welcome, always appreciate a bit of mystery.