# Reset DOM state with Jasmine and Phantom JS

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs

As pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347201/jasmine-fails-when-same-test-is-run-twice) question, it looks like my DOM need to be reset in  all my "beforeEach" callbacks.

How do I do that? I cannot seem to find it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is usually done by loading the page again, since you cannot simply take a snapshot of the DOM and restore it. I'm not familiar with Jasmine, though.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thank you for your reply. However I never touch any 'page'. It seems it is done automatically. I don't even load any url =/. Do you know how could I do that?